# Через дефис - таки?

Tags: орфография

*ДКП таки придется заплатить за несостоявшийся цирк.* Частицу "таки" через дефис?

Comment: А кто такой (что такое) ДКП?

Comment: Дом культуры профсоюзов

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку ДКП - не наречие, не частица и не глагол, то без дефиса (*Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати, гл. XVII: Правописание частиц §63, п.4*):

http://tululu.org/read56104/41/

Но если перенести "таки" в позицию *после* глагола, то получится с дефисом ("ДКП придётся-таки...").

Answer (score 1):

Главное слово в "ДКП" существительное, а с существительными частица "таки" пишется ***раздельно.***

Я бы на Вашем месте всё же поставил "таки" после "придётся", так звучит лучше. Интуиция мне подсказывает, что в таких случаях "таки" чаще всего ставят после глагола. Тогда дефис ***нужно*** будет поставить:

*ДКП придется-таки заплатить за несостоявшийся цирк.*

Answer (score 0):

В приведённом Вами примере дефис не нужен.

[**См. ПАС:**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

> **§144.** Пишутся раздельно сочетания со следующими частицами.
>
> <...>
>
> 3. С частицей *таки,* **предшествующей** слову, к которому она относится (обычно сказуемому), напр.: *Он таки приехал вовремя; Он таки рад её
>      приезду.*